# как извлечь код (unicode) i-той буквы из из текста?

Tags: java, scala

дан текст, цикл for по i проходит этот текст и мне в определённый момент цикла нужно взять unicode обрабатываемый буквой, каким оператором это можно сделать?

PS речь идёт о таких кодах как:
a code:97
b code:98
c code:99
и т.д.

Answer (score 0):

```
char character = 'a';
int code = (int)character; //ваш код символа
```